# How to fix XCode SwiftUI error PreviewUpdateTimedOutError: Updating took more than 5 seconds

Tags: xcode, swiftui, gif, macos-catalina

This error only started happening once I made a second .swift view. This is also happening to another piece of code I'm making and it also started when I added a second .swift file. I'm running Xcode version 12.4 on macOS Catalina 10.15.7
The code for the content view:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {

        GifImage(name: "boulder.gif")



        }

    }





struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {

    static var previews: some View {

        ContentView()

    }

}
```

The code for the other view:

```
import SwiftUI

import WebKit


struct GifImage: UIViewRepresentable {

    private let name: String

    init( name: String) {

        self.name = name

    }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {

        let webView = WKWebView()

        let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: name, withExtension: "gif")!

        let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url)

        webView.load(data, mimeType: "image/gif",

                     characterEncodingName: "UTF-8",

                     baseURL: url.deletingLastPathComponent()

                     )

        return webView

    

    }

    func updateUIView( _ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {

        uiView.reload()

       

    }

}



struct GifImage_Previews: PreviewProvider {

    static var previews: some View {

        GifImage(name: "boulder")

    }

}
```

I tried displaying a GIF in my app.

Comment: It's looking for an image called `"boulder.gif.gif"` right now -- remove the `.gif` from the call site

Answer (score 0):

Keep as less dependencies as possible for the view. Run "Product -> Build" before previewing - it helps to build missing files (preview needs complete app compilation).

Comment: BTW, a good practice is to move all small UI pieces into a separate framework which is part of the main project - Project / File -> New -> Target / Frameworks & Libraries -> Framework. But copy the code before trying if you will rollback later.